# OracleGGCreateNextBatch table in different location?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I am trying to use Oracle GoldenGate to connect a read-only MSSQL-DB to an Oracle-DB.

In ggsci when I try the command for the MSSQL source DB:  ADD TRANDATA MySchema.TableName

I get lots of errors because the db is read-only and it looks like the command is trying to add a gg table OracleGGCreateNextBatch to my source schema.

Is there a way to put this table in another schema that is not read-only??

Comment: OGG is a tool that replicates changes in the database. What is the point of replicating a read-only database? What to replicate if nothing is changing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, it was not an intelligent question(that is not an opinion, that is a fact, I am very aware of the intelligence of this author, because I am him!)

There is no reason to do CDC on a read-only database, because there is no transactions to capture.  Thanks to Adam for pointing that out.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18109677)

Comment: Hey Reviewwer TooMuch design,   You should review this a bit deeper.  The author wrote a stupid question.  It is a stupid question, but could be of use to others that also have the same stupid question.  The answer is there is no reason to try to do CDC on a read-only DB that does not have any transaction logs.  Saying that the author posted a stupid question is not an opinion, because such opinions are not allowed on Stack Overflow.  It is a fact that it was a stupid question.  I have directly talked to the author about this....... maybe a closer look a the authors name and my name might help